# Exception when i am trying to execute delete @Query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I am trying to execute this @Query in my EmployeeRepository class

```
    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "DELETE FROM Employee e WHERE e.department.companyBranch.id = :companyBranchId")
    void deleteAllByCompanyBranchId(@Param("companyBranchId") Long companyBranchId);
```

But I am getting this exception

```
Column "D1_0.COMPANY_BRANCH_ID" not found; SQL statement:
delete from employee where d1_0.company_branch_id=? [42122-214]] [delete from employee where d1_0.company_branch_id=?]; SQL [delete from employee where d1_0.company_branch_id=?]] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Столбец "D1_0.COMPANY_BRANCH_ID" не найден
Column "D1_0.COMPANY_BRANCH_ID" not found; SQL statement:
delete from employee where d1_0.company_branch_id=? [42122-214]
```

I think it is somehow connected to JPQL conventions, but I am not sure. By looking at my exception I can say that the query is trying to find the `COMPANY_BRANCH_ID` field in `EMPLOYEE` table, but I am not sure about it.

This is my entity classes:

Employee:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DEPARTMENT_ID", nullable = false)
    private Department department;
}
```

Department

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "DEPARTMENT")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Department {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH_ID", nullable = false)
    private CompanyBranch companyBranch;
}
```

CompanyBranch

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMPANY_BRANCH")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class CompanyBranch {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure you can use this level of nested queries.

I'd try to go with something like :

```java
@Query(value = "DELETE FROM Employee e WHERE e.department.id IN (SELECT d.id from Departement d where d.companyBranch.id = :companyBranchId"))
```

That's the kind of query you would normally do in plain sql.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It helped me, but instead of using '=' I needed to use 'IN', otherwise there was an exception, the final query looks like this `DELETE FROM Employee e WHERE e.department.id IN (SELECT d.id from Department d where d.companyBranch.id = :companyBranchId)`

Comment: I was a bit afraid of that point, I'll edit my answer to fit the final query :)